# Android screen size

Tags: android

I see that the minimum screen diagonal size for Android is listed as 2.6". I am looking at custom building a device with screen size 2.2" to 2.4" and resolution 320X240. Want to know if Android works on smaller screens. Do I need to write any display drivers to support the smaller screens? Does physical size really matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're custom-building a device, then you'll need to write or make use of the available display drivers for the particular hardware you're sourcing for that device.

The physical size doesn't matter so much as Android doesn't directly map the screen density values used by the framework to the actual physical display density.

However, in terms of actually being usable, going down to 2.2" seems a bit too small.  The Sony Ericsson X10 Mini has a screen size of about 2.5" and I can tell you that, while it's usable and generally readable, it seems pretty close to the lower bound of usability to me.